# tableView: cellForRowAtIndexPath: get called not only for visible cells?

Tags: ios, uitableview

I have a tableView with sections, which could be opened and closed. So, when I tap on a section to open it, it is getting filled up with cells and `-(UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)` get called exactly as much times as I provided in `-(NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section`.

Is that correct? Shouldn't it be just number of visible cells?

Because in my case I have bad situation: I have a lot of custom cells (50~100 cells) and calling `-(UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)` for each cell slows down the opening of a section, cause each time reading from nib is performed and cell content is being populated with image. 
I've check visibility of cell inside `-(UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)` like this:

```
if ([[self.tableView indexPathsForVisibleRows] containsObject:indexPath])
    NSLog(@"visible %@", indexPath);
```

and it shows that from out of 45 cells, only 6 or 7 are visible. Others are out of visible area. But creating cells still performed.
Here is the code:

```
-(UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath    {
static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"IVCell";
IVCamera *camera = [server.cameras objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];

IVServerListViewCell *cell = (IVServerListViewCell*)[tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
if (cell == nil) {
    [[NSBundle mainBundle] loadNibNamed:@"IVServerListCell" owner:self options:nil];
    cell = (IVServerListViewCell*)_tableViewCell;
    self.tableViewCell = nil;

}

[cell textLabel].text = camera.cameraName;
cell.preview = camera.preview;
cell.userData = camera; 
cell.isEnabled = (server.isInactive)?NO:camera.isOnline;

return cell;
}
```

Is it still correct? Or am I missing something?

Comment: for dynamically sized cells, the tableView needs to have an idea what the contentSize is for scrolling performance.  If you don't specify an estimatedCellHeight then it will load each and every cell.  To solve your problem, just add an estimatedHeightForRowAt with an approximate height and you will see after that it will only load the visible cells.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Well, I somehow dealt with my problem. Here are my ideas and thoughts how I came to the solution. Maybe it could be helpful to somebody.

I've instructed memory allocations and call stack using Instruments during opening section events. It showed me, that the majority of time is spent on loading cell from nib file.

Firstly, that I've done was **reducing the size of nib file**, i.e. minimizing the number of views used in custom tableview cell (now its only 2 views and 2 labels, instead of 6 views, 2 images and 2 labels before). It gave me some improve in cells loading. Apple documentation suggests to use as few as possible views and do not use transparency. So be attentive to these suggestions.

Secondly, as I discovered earlier, that not all cell are visible which are created by `-(UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)`, I decided to reduce somehow the number of loadings new cells from nib file. To achieve this, I've came to simple idea: return blank default cells for invisible rows, while load custom cells from nib for visible ones. Here is the piece of code:

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    if ([self index:indexPath isInvisibleInTableView:tableView])
        return [self getBlankCellForTableView:tableView];

    // the rest of the method is the same
    ...
}

-(BOOL)index:(NSIndexPath*)indexPath isInvisibleInTableView:(UITableView*)tableView
{
    NSMutableArray *visibleIndexPaths = [self getExtendedVisibleIndexPathsForTableView:tableView];

    return ![visibleIndexPaths containsObject:indexPath];
}

-(UITableViewCell*)getBlankCellForTableView:(UITableView*)tableView
{
    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"IVBlankCell"];
    if (!cell)
        cell = [[[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:@"IVBlankCell"] autorelease];

    return cell;
}
```

As you can see, I'm not using just `-(NSArray*)indexPathsForVisibleRows` method of tableview for detecting visible cells. Instead, I've wrote my own method `-(NSMutableArray*)getExtendedVisibleIndexPathsForTableView:(UITableView*)tableView`. It was necessary because for some reason, when using `-(NSArray*)indexPathsForVisibleRows` the cells that are next to the last one visible cell or the cells that are previous to the first one visible cell were created as blank cells and looked like empty cells while scrolling. To overcome this, in `-(NSMutableArray*)getExtendedVisibleIndexPathsForTableView: (UITableView*)tableView` i'm adding border cells to the visible array cells:

```
-(NSMutableArray*)getExtendedVisibleIndexPathsForTableView:(UITableView*)tableView{
    NSArray *visibleIPs = [tableView indexPathsForVisibleRows];

    if (!visibleIPs || ![visibleIPs count])
        return [NSMutableArray array];

    NSIndexPath *firstVisibleIP = [visibleIPs objectAtIndex:0];
    NSIndexPath *lastVisibleIP = [visibleIPs objectAtIndex:[visibleIPs count]-1];

    NSIndexPath *prevIndex = ([firstVisibleIP row])?[NSIndexPath indexPathForRow:[firstVisibleIP row]-1  inSection:[firstVisibleIP section]]:nil;
    NSIndexPath *nextIndex = [NSIndexPath indexPathForRow:[lastVisibleIP row]+1 inSection:[lastVisibleIP section]];

    NSMutableArray *exVisibleIndexPaths = [NSMutableArray arrayWithArray:[tableView indexPathsForVisibleRows]];

    if (prevIndex)
        [exVisibleIndexPaths addObject:prevIndex];
    [exVisibleIndexPaths addObject:nextIndex];

    return exVisibleIndexPaths;
}
```

Thereby, I've reduced the time of opening sections with large number of custom cells, which was proved by Instruments tracing and felt while experiencing the app.

Comment: that was awesome, me too had an issue like this, your technique was so useful that the issue is solved.

Answer (score 7):

increase your

> estimatedRowHeight of UITableview.

Comment: Thanks man, great solution!

Answer (score 4):

Simply add estimated height for UITableViewCell

Problem In my case was:  cellforRowAtIndexPath was getting called array.count number of times, whereas, displayed cells where less than array.count.

To resolve this issue, I have just replaced,

- (CGFloat)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView heightForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath

with,

- (CGFloat)tableView:(UITableView )tableView estimatedHeightForRowAtIndexPath:(nonnull NSIndexPath )indexPath;

Answer (score 2):

check your tableview size.
may be that your tableview height is very large that it keep loading cells until your cell fills all tableview size..

Comment: I was setting the estimatedRowHeight of tableView to a low value of 100pts when I knew all my cells would be of height > 320pts. This was causing unnecessary loading of extra cells until 100 + 100 + ... > tableView visible bounds. Then I changed estimatedRowHeight to 320 and number of rows loaded got reduced.

Answer (score 0):

This seems correct yes. the idea about optimizing the loading itself lies within how "dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier" works.
if u are loading the image from a remote location this is where u would want to optimize the code. but not from the loading of cells as this looks correct here.

Comment: that sounds sad. i've temporarily turned off populating cells with images, and there is still small annoying delay for opening section with 42 cells compared to section with just 9 cells. i think here is the only way - to reduce the size of nib of custom cell and reduce the number of uiviews used in it. how do you think?

Comment: I'm curious how you are expanding/collapsing the sections in the UITableView. because that isn't there by default.

Comment: using `insertRowsAtIndexPaths:withRowAnimation:` and `deleteRowsAtIndexPaths: withRowAnimation:`

Comment: does that mean your sections are normal cells, just looking differently?. try reloading the tableview with adding those cells. you will need some code added to
-(UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)
to filter if the cells are to be returned, and also you will need to change the count of the cells.

Comment: no. sections are "sections" in the meaning as UITableView it defines. so cells for them are generated in special `-(UIView*)tableView:(UITableView*)tableView viewForHeaderInSection:(NSInteger)section` method of the delegate

Comment: I'd recommend to try reloading the tableview instead of adding the cells with the animation. I suspect the animation is the one to be responsible for that slow down. using simulator or device ?

Comment: i can see slow down on device. simulator seems faster

Answer (score 0):

I used some similar technique but since indexPathsForVisibleRows is sorted you don't need to use containsObject. Instead you can just do:

```
//
// Checks if indexPath is visible in current scroll state, we are expanding bounds by 1
// because the cells that are next to the last one visible or the cells that are previous
// to the first one visible could look empty while scrolling.
//
- (BOOL)isIndexPathVisible:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    NSInteger row = [indexPath row];
    NSArray *visible = [self.tableView indexPathsForVisibleRows];
    NSInteger count = [visible count];
    NSInteger first = (count > 0) ? MAX([visible[0] row] - 1, 0): 0;
    NSInteger last = (count > 1) ? [visible[1] row] + 1: first + 2;

    return row >= first && row <= last;
}
```

By the way; this assumes that you are using only one section. It won't work for more than one section.

Answer (score 0):

Adding an else solved my problem.
Where I reseted any changes that were made to the cell.

```
if (! self.cell) {
    self.cell = [[LanguageCell alloc]initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:cellIdentifier];
    self.cell.accessoryType = UITableViewCellAccessoryNone;
}
else
{
    self.cell.checkImage.image = NO;

}
```