# Loading many records in UITableView

Tags: ios

I am loading a UITableView in this way:

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableViewLocal cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {

static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"Cell";
CustomTableViewCell *cell = [tableViewLocal dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
if (cell == nil) {
    cell = [[CustomTableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleSubtitle reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
}

for(UIView *subview in cell.contentView.subviews)
{
    [subview removeFromSuperview];
}


UIImage* img;
UIImageView *imv = [[UIImageView alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(5, 5, 60, 60)];


    if(isFiltered == TRUE){
        cell.textLabel.text = [filteredTableData objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
        cell.textLabel.font = [UIFont systemFontOfSize:14];
    }

    if(isFiltered == FALSE){
        cell.textLabel.text = [itemArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
        cell.textLabel.font = [UIFont systemFontOfSize:14];
        cell.detailTextLabel.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"date added: %@", [DKStoreManager dateFileWasCreatedWithFileName:[itemArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row] inFolderNumber:[_FolderCode intValue] forUser:[_PassedUserID intValue] andType:_FolderType]];
    }

    NSData* data = [DKStoreManager loadFileWithName:[itemArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row] forFolderNumber:[_FolderCode intValue] forUser:userID andType:_FolderType];
    img = [[UIImage imageWithData:data] cropToSize:CGSizeMake(320, 320) usingMode:NYXCropModeCenter];
    imv.image = img;
    [cell.contentView addSubview:imv];


cell.accessoryType = UITableViewCellAccessoryDisclosureIndicator;

return cell;
}
```

As you can see I have an itemArray with all the names of the files, and for each cell I load the relative NSData in this way:

```
NSData* data = [DKStoreManager loadFileWithName:[itemArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row] forFolderNumber:[_FolderCode intValue] forUser:userID andType:_FolderType];
```

Since it also loads images (and there may be more than 300 cells), the UI frees.

I have tried loading only the visible cells using the accepted answer of this link:

[tableView: cellForRowAtIndexPath: get called not only for visible cells?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9286025/tableview-cellforrowatindexpath-get-called-not-only-for-visible-cells)

however all of the cells are loaded at the same time. I have no idea of how to do this...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

cellForRowAtIndexPath gets called when the tableView reloads as well as when the user scrolls. The UI freeze could be due to the fact that your calling

```
for(UIView *subview in cell.contentView.subviews)
{
    [subview removeFromSuperview];
}

UIImageView *imv = [[UIImageView alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(5, 5, 60, 60)];
```

which means that every time the user scrolls , you are iterating through all the subViews and removing them, as well as allocating UIimageView's  at the same time, this is not a good way to go about displaying content. You can use the tableViewCell's default imageView property to display your image. After getting you image just say

```
cell.imageView.image = img;
```